# How to loop all functions?

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop

I am working on a project and I've got stuck :(.... I have 9 (nine) functions with the name: 
getM1(), getM2(), getM3(), getM4()....getM5(). And all of these functions return a value.

Now I need to make a loop which checks the value of these functions. Something like this:

```
public void show()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        if (obj.getM[i]() == 1)
        {
          .......;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course it shows me an error because the getM doesn't contain any index..
And I wanted to ask you, can you help me with this? Or does anybody have another idea how could I check all getM() functions?

Comment: What's the signature of these functions? Are they `int getM1()`, `int getM2()`, etc?

Comment: Instead of 9 functions, you need an [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: yes they all are int getM1()....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about putting the functions into an Array:

```
var functionList = new [] { obj.getM1, obj.getM2, ... };
```

And then loop at it

```
foreach (var f in functionList)
{
    if (f() == 1) 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create an array of `Func<int>` delegates and use it to access your methods:

```
var functions = new Func<int>[9];
functions[0] = getM1;
functions[1] = getM2;
functions[2] = getM3;
// (...)

for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    if (functions[i]() == 1)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to initialize array using collection initializer.

Comment: Why do you think it's better?

Comment: Faster and more reliable in my opinion.

Comment: @abatishchev I thought it compiles to the same thing, so speed shouldn't be affected.  Still, a collection initializer means much cleaner and more readable code IMO, which outweighs other considerations here and would make it my preferred choice, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the methods with this:

```
int getM(int index)
```

If this and the other solutions suggested really don't make any sense, you can do what you want using reflection:

```
var t = obj.GetType();
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    var m = t.GetMethod("getM" + i);
    int result = (int)m.Invoke(obj, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of `Func<T>`, where `T` is the return type of your functions. Then you would be able to call your functions more or less the way you described in your code.

For example, if your functions return `int`, you can do this:

```
Func<int>[] ems = new Func<int>[] {
    () => obj.getM1(), () => obj.getM2(), () => obj.getM3()
,   () => obj.getM4(), () => obj.getM5(), () => obj.getM6()
,   () => obj.getM7(), () => obj.getM8(), () => obj.getM9()
};
foreach (Func<int> em in ems)
{
    if (em() == 1)
    {
      .......;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can replace `() => obj.getM1()` with `obj.getM1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Show()
{
   Func<int>[] arr = new[]
   {
       obj.GetM1,
       obj.GetM2,
       ...
   };
   foreach(Func<int> func in arr)
   {
       if (func() == 1)
       {
           //
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store all of these methods in a list, loop over the list an execute them.

```
var funcList = new List<Func<int>>{ getM1, getM2, ... };
```

Then you can loop over the list and execute each method.

```
foreach(var func in funList)
{
    if(func() == 1)
        ...
}
```

Comment: It's better to initialize list using collection initializer. And use array instead, too.